# Getting the error "DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found." while trying to import tensorflow for Windows in Anaconda using PyCharm

Tags: python, dll, anaconda

I'm using windows 10 x64
Anaconda 2018.12.0.0
Python 3.6

I can't figure out the problem. I've tried reinstalling numpy but still nothing.

Below is the complete error I'm getting in the PYcharm

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf-1_9-36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core__init__.py", line 16, in 
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf-1_9-36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 12, in 
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf-1_9-36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 6, in 
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ismae/PycharmProjects/Test1/first", line 1, in 
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf-1_9-36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf-1_9-36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 47, in 
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf-1_9-36\lib\site-packages\numpy__init__.py", line 142, in 
    from . import core
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf-1_9-36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core__init__.py", line 47, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
Here is how to proceed:
- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
- If you are simply trying to use the numpy version that you have installed:
  your installation is broken - please reinstall numpy.
- If you have already reinstalled and that did not fix the problem, then:
  1. Check that you are using the Python you expect (you're using C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf-1_9-36\python.exe),
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy versions you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

```
 Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
 an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.
```

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063285/numpy-is-already-installed-with-anaconda-but-i-get-an-importerror-dll-load-fail/58194133#58194133)

You need to update your environment variable "PATH" adding **\Library\bin**

Note: Follow this step only if you have already installed numpy and still facing issue.

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python<version>\Library\bin
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda<version>\Library\bin\
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked! :)))